# regex help for validators

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression validator to validate that text fields contain only numbers between 00 - 31 (note that it should allow both 05 and 5), another regex for numbers 01 -12 (again, it should allow both 05 and 5), and another regex for numbers between 1920 - 2009.

How can i do this?

Comment: I'm curious, why would you use a regex to validate a date?  

Can't you convert the individual values to ints and test the number range that way?  

Or try DateTime.Parse - and it's bad if it throws a FormatException?

Answer (score 2):

What not use the range validator and put the min and max dates in with a datatype of Date.
So minValue= 1/1/1920, maxValue= 1/12/2009.
You can even set the maxvalue on a page load (no postback check) with todays date.

Answer (score 1):

1920-2009:

```
"^(19[2-9][0-9])|(200[0-9])$" or simplier: "^((19[2-9])|(200))([0-9])$"
```

Answer (score 0):

00-31 case

```
"^(0?[0-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)|(31))$"
```

01-12 case

```
"^(0?[1-9])|(10)|(11)|(12)$"
```

Comment: Your second expression does not match 11.

Comment: @apathetic, changed it to match 11

Comment: @f0b0s.iu9.info, I don't. I was being overcareful in my original answer.